# FastCGI script can't find libfcgi.so.0 in Apache 2.4.6 and mod_fastcgi

Tags: c, apache, centos7, mod-fastcgi

This is my simple hello-world FastCGI script written in C.

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
int count = 0;
while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
           "\r\n"
           "<title>FastCGI Hello!</title>"
           "<h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>"
           "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
            ++count, getenv("SERVER_NAME"));
}
```

It works fine if I compiled it using static linking.

```
gcc -o "test.fcg" "test.c" /usr/local/lib/libfcgi.a
```

But when using dynamic linking...

```
gcc -o "test.fcg" -lfcgi "test.c"
```

It fails whith the following error in Apache's `error_log`.

```
/var/www/fcgi-bin/test.fcg: error while loading shared libraries: libfcgi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Thu Mar 05 14:04:22.707096 2015] [:warn] [pid 6544] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/var/www/fcgi-bin/test.fcg" (pid 6967) terminated by calling exit with status '127'
[Thu Mar 05 14:04:22.707527 2015] [:warn] [pid 6544] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/var/www/fcgi-bin/test.fcg" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
```

So I'm telling Apache and mod_fastcgi to look for that file where it's located setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in `httpd.conf`...

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
```

...and `fastcgi.conf`.

```
FastCgiConfig -initial-env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib -idle-timeout 20 -maxClassProcesses 1
```

Using a static-linked script, `getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` returns `/usr/local/lib`, but dynamic-linked scripts are still throwing not found errors for `libfcgi.so.0`.

Any ideas to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue with nginx, I fixed it by using `rpath` option.

Not sure if it will help with Apache. Try building your binary like this:

```
gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lfcgi -o test.fcg
```

Make sure the library file `libfcgi.so.0` is present at `/usr/local/lib`.

If you don't have access to `/usr/local/lib`, then create the `lib` folder in your `$HOME`, and copy the library file there. And update the `rpath` to point to there. For example, if your `$HOME` is `/home/xyz`, then you would build like:

```
gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath /home/xyz/lib -lfcgi -o test.fcg
```

Sometimes I use this trick to load newer libraries than what is installed on the system.

Comment: The `-rpath` option was the trick. Thanks buddy! You'll receive your +50 in a few hours.