# how to fix custom fastcgi program written in C

Tags: c, apache, cgi, executable, fastcgi

This is my program:

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0){
    FCGI_printf("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
    FCGI_printf("<h1>Test</h1>\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

These are the options I added to the apache config for the virtual host I'm working with:

```
SetHandler fastcgi-script
Options +ExecCGI
```

I also have the following line in the same apache config file:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
```

I followed directions at [FastCGI script can't find libfcgi.so.0 in Apache 2.4.6 and mod_fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883708/fastcgi-script-cant-find-libfcgi-so-0-in-apache-2-4-6-and-mod-fastcgi) to compile my program.

If I execute the compiled program directly, I receive the familiar "segmentation fault" on screen. When I try executing it via the server at `http://127.0.0.1/a.out`, I get an internal server error and the following in the error_log:

```
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:10 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" started (pid 9331)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:10 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" (pid 9331) terminated due to uncaught signal '11' (Segmentation fault)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:15 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" restarted (pid 9333)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:15 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" (pid 9333) terminated due to uncaught signal '11' (Segmentation fault)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:20 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" restarted (pid 9334)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:20 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" (pid 9334) terminated due to uncaught signal '11' (Segmentation fault)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:25 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" restarted (pid 9335)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:25 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" (pid 9335) terminated due to uncaught signal '11' (Segmentation fault)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:25 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:26 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:29 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:32 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:35 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:38 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:41 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:44 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec)
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:44 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out"
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:44 2015] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/a.out" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Tue Nov 17 00:48:44 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: FastCGI: stat() of "/usr/local/apache2/virt1/favicon.ico" failed
```

Its basically telling me that apache is attempting to start the program a few times but the program returns segmentation fault.

The result I was expecting was the word `Test` in bold in a web browser.

How do I fix my program to make it compatible with fast-cgi so that I can execute it via a web browser?

I don't want to resort to the slow CGI interface which is why I'm trying to use functions beginning with FCGI.

Comment: How did you compiled this ?
What is the executable file name ?

Comment: I used `gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lfcgi` and it created a.out then I moved a.out to `/usr/local/apache2/virt1/` which is the document root for `127.0.0.1`.